# Cómo hago un diseño de base de datos sin redundancia

Tags: base-de-datos

Voy a hacer una base de datos relacional de esta tabla:

[image]

Como se puede ver, tengo varios campos y todos ellos tienen los mismos dos sub campos (atributos) y a partir de aquí surgió mi problema con respecto al diseño.

Lo que se me ocurrió es que cada campo en verdad va a ser una tabla (archivo), y las categorías van a ser la clave primaria, sin embargo tengo en total 8 campos con 17 categorías (registros) y creo que esa solución realmente es un poco redundante, porque obviamente los sub campos se repiten y a parte tendría 8 tablas cada una con dos campos y 17 registros, sin sumar que no veo como relacionarlas luego debido a que son campos con valores numéricos que tienen como único fin llegar a un total.

[image]

Si me pueden dar ideas de como diseñar o ideas de algún tema en concreto que pueda indagar para realizar ésto, cabe mencionar aún no he recibido clases de bases de datos, sin embargo he estado siguiendo tutoriales, pero siempre presentan diseños muy simples y luego pasan directo al SQL.

Comment: No tengo claro que la pregunta se on-topic; he abierto [esta pregunta en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3709/preguntas-sobre-modelos-relacionales-entidad-relaci%c3%b3n) para consultarlo. En todo caso los modelos relaciones son **semánticos**; eso quiere decir que un modelo será correcto o no en función de la información que se quiera representar y para qué se quiera usar; no hay un mecanismo automático de "tengo estos campos, este es el modelo". No se empieza desde la tabla y se obtiene el modelo, es al revés.

Comment: Bienvenido. Hoy día se programa pensando en la realidad. Si explicaras mejor el problema, basado en la realidad, quizá quedaría más claro cómo ayudarte. Cuando escribes cosas como `Campo1, Campo2, CampoN`... o como `Sub1, Sub2, SubN...` uno no puede tener la más mínima idea de lo que se trata. Ese diseño se puede resolver quizá con dos o tres tablas relacionadas, pero sin poner un ejemplo más claro de lo que quieres cualquier respuesta sería aventurarse en el vacío. ¿Qué representa `Campo1` personas, vehículos, ciudades? ... ¿qué representa `Sub1`?  ... ¿y `CampoN`?  ... ¿y `Sub9999`?

Comment: Para diseñar una base de datos, no basta con saber los campos. Hay que conocer las reglas de negocios. A veces, las mismas son documentos con cientos de paginas (depende del tamaño del sistema). Los nombres de los campos, no dicen nada sobre el diseño de la base de datos. Hay que saber para que se usan, que contienen, y como es la carga de los mismos, la cantidad de informacion que guardan, la necesidad de recuperarlos. Te cuento todo esto, porque dices que no viste bases de datos. Entonces, No hay un modelo optimo real, solo hay un modelo que funciona para ese caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver estas tratando de forzar un modelo 3-dimensional en uno bidimensional, lo correcto sería tener las siguientes tablas:

```
+ Categoria
  - Id (PK)
  - Nombre 

+ Campo
  - Id (PK)
  - Nombre

+ Sexo
  - Id (PK)
  - Nombre

+ Datos
  - IdCategoria (PK)
  - IdCampo (PK)
  - IdSexo (PK)
  - Valor
```

De esta manera los valores pueden variar en 3 dimensiones (categoría, campo y sexo (lo cual creo que es tu subcampo)) y la tabla Datos (o como quieras llamarle) contiene los valores correspondiente al cruce de las 3 dimensiones.

La tabla Datos tiene un llave primaria compuesta por los 3 Ids de las otras tres tablas

Este modelo tiene las siguiente ventajas.

1. Permite crecer en cualquiera de las 3 dimensiones

   Si se necesitan aumentar las categorías, los "campo" o los sexos se pueden agregar mas filas a las tablas correspondientes.
2. Almacena los valores numéricos en una sola tabla.

   Esto permite que los totales pueden ser calculados agrupándolos por cualquier combinación de campos, no solamente por "campo" y además no es necesario almacenarlos.
3. Permite hacer crecer el modelo en dimensiones también.

   Si luego fuera necesario agregar una 4 variable, por ejemplo `Nivel`, se podría crear una nueva tabla, con lo valores correspondientes y modificar la tabla `Datos` para agregar un nuevo campo y volver a crear una llave primaria con los 4 ids para seguir clasificándolo los datos aún más.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Opción:**

Puedes hacer una tabla tal que así:

```
CREATE TABLE mitabla (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, campo ingeter, 
                        subcampo integer, category integer, dato integer);
```

De esta manera podrás luego usar `GROUP BY category`cuando quieras el total de una categoria o `GROUP BY campo`cuando te quieras centrar solo en un campo.

**2) Opción:**

Otra opción es hacer una tabla con campo,subcampo y dato por cada categoria. Y añadir un idIndiceCasilla, en todas las tablas. De esta manera luego podrás unir todas usando `join using idIndiceCasilla`.

**3) Opción:**

Y si realmente quieres usar una tabla relacional ya sería crear 3 tablas.

Una tabla con un idColumna (indicando la columna en tu foto de la tabla):

```
CREATE TABLE miColumna (idColumna INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, campo ingeter, 
                            subcampo integer);
```

Otra tabla con el idCategoria (indicando la fila en tu foto de la tabla), y el dato:

```
CREATE TABLE miFila (idCategoria INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dato ingeter);
```

Y la tabla relacional (indicando la unión de fila y columna para cada posición). Esta habría que introducirla a mano.

```
 CREATE TABLE mi (idColumna INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                             idCategoria INTEGER PRIMARY KEY );
```

En este caso tendrías que usar un `join`de las tres tablas y sentencias condicionales para obtener tus datos.